# Selecting value from drop down vba scraping

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to select a name from a dropdown using Vba. However it is unable to do so.

**VBA:**

```
ie.document.Body.getElementsByTagName("SELECT").Item(0).selectedIndex = "2"
ie.document.Body.getElementsByTagName("SELECT").Item(0).Value = "Yearly"
```

Page Source:

> MonthlyHalf YearlyYearly

Also, I am using IE10

Comment: i'm not sure there is a rule about this, but i can definitely say I'm not going to click on an unknown external site as a resource needed to understand your problem. put the parts that are important in your question as code snippets.

Comment: What is your question? What code do you have that's not working? Why do you include some tag elements, what do they have to do with anything?  What's the end goal?  We'll need a bit more information before we can help.

Comment: I am writing a code for web scraping. I want to extract some data from a website. The website has a drop down "Choose payment mode" containing three values. I want to select "Yearly" using VBA. However, I am unable to do so. I want to know the VBA code for doing so.

Comment: This is the page source: ><div class=dropDivCon><select id=paymentFrequency class="custom-class1 custom-class2" style=position:relative;border:none;top:9px;left:9px;width:167px><option value=MONTHLY-ECS selected>Monthly<option value=HALF-YEARLY>Half Yearly<option value=YEARLY>Yearly</select></div>

Answer (score 0):

You did almost all the job by yourself, just a little note - string values are CASE SENSITIVE. Therefore you are using upper case values in options and should assign upper case values in the script:

```
ie.document.Body.getElementsByTagName("SELECT").Item(0).Value = "YEARLY"
```

this one should work!

P.S. Just for any case I add JavaScript code too, as it slightly differs from VB and it works, I've just checked:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT").item(0).value = "YEARLY"
```

Good luck with that :)

Comment: Hi, I tried using ie.document.Body.getElementsByTagName("SELECT").Item(0).Value = "YEARLY" in VBA. However, there is no change on the website. I have tried it on both IE 10 and IE8.

Comment: Are you limited to use only VBScript for scripting? I would advice you to go with JavaScript instead. I really could not make any VBScript run onto the page, I know that's probably my fault, but there also are almost no resources online and the examples I took from MSDN still do NOT work :) So I strongly advice you to change to JavaScript if you are not limited to VBScript.

Comment: And please stop calling that VBA, VBA is Visual Basic for Applications which is totally different technology from the one you are using. Here is Wiki page about what VBA is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications

Comment: Thanks GSazheniuk. The problem is donot know how to use JavaScript. I have also learned VB recently and hence was trying my luck on it. However it did not work. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: So while you have not gone to far it is better to stop with VBScript and re-start with Javascript. And here is the Javascript solution to your question: https://jsfiddle.net/qmcqjnoa/